# Python Pandas in colab:UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd3 in position 0: invalid continuation byteUnicodeDecodeError:

Tags: python, pandas, google-colaboratory, kaggle

guys i have been trying to load some datasets from kaggle which has been downloaded already.

```
hist_trans = pd.read_csv('historical_transactions.csv')

new_trans = pd.read_csv('new_merchant_transactions.csv')


train = pd.read_csv('train.csv', parse_dates=['first_active_month'])

test = pd.read_csv('test.csv', parse_dates=['first_active_month'])
```

And i had this error
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd3 in position 0: invalid continuation byte

Comment: have you tried a different encoding? the `read_csv` method taks as param `encoding =[ ]` try `encoding = 'ISO-8859-1'`. it might help

Answer (score 5):

Try encoding option in read_csv like below.

```
read_csv('file', encoding = "utf-8")
```

or

```
read_csv('file', encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
```

Comment: read_csv('file', encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
This worked for me. Thanks.